# ASP.NET URL Routing with wildcard

Tags: asp.net, url, routes, wildcard

I have a CMS system that I am using Routing to get the page name. I have the need to have unlimited values (sub directories, product names, different localizations) between the first item and the last item (page name).

For example:

/Products/Computers/ComputerType1/

And

/Productos/Ordenadores/ComputerType1/

Where ComputerType1 is the page name.

```
routes.Add(new Route("{*route}/{pageName}", routeHandler));
```

I cannot find a way to make the middle part ({*route}) of the route to be the wildcard so that unlimited number of sub directories can be put in front of the page name. Currently I have only been able to get around this with having a default wildcard route such as:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{*route}", routeHandler));
```

to catch everything. However, the wildcard seems to also be letting in gif urls even thou I have it specified as ignore above in the route code as:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.png/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.jpg/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.ico/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.pdf/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Should this be handled thru a custom route handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you should create a route handler for cases like these
simple create a `class` and derive it from `RouteBase`
override the `GetRouteData` method
in this method you can access the current `httpcontext` and thus you can access the requested `URL`
so u can route accordingly.
for more info on custom routes visit this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application

Comment: The custom route is working. However I am still having an issue with the wildcard route catching a gif file located in the "App_Themes/directoryname/images/image1.gif". The route ignore of routes.Ignore("{resource}.gif/{*pathInfo}"); is only working if the image is located in the root directory. One thing I noticed is that the image file is referenced in the theme but the file doesn't exist where the other image files in the theme do exist and are not trying to be routed. I am thinking about adding a route ignore based on "/App_Themes/{folder} .....". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the issue is that the gif image is referenced in the theme but the acutal file does not exist so IIS cannot ignore the "file" and is routing it as a catchall url.